# My favicon works on every other web browser except for Google Chrome, idk why but it just doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Starting off yes I tried clearing my cache:

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charsey="utf-8" />
  <title>Title cuz eh</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/favicon.png">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="48x48" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>
```

Comment: "Google" isn't a web browser. Do you mean Chrome?

Comment: maybe you mean Chrome?

Comment: try a hard refresh.

Comment: You misspelt `charset`.

Comment: Yes I meant Google Chrome

Comment: Yeah let me try fixing the charset part real quick

Comment: Fixed charset nothing changed

Comment: Tried almost everything nothing worked